# Splitting a list of objects into multiple separate lists based on a given criteria

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Consider the following list:

```
var headers = new List<TableHeader>()
{
    new TableHeader("Column1", 3),
    new TableHeader("Column2", 2),
    new TableHeader("Column3", 1, Alignment.Right),
    new TableHeader("Column4", 1),
    new TableHeader("Column5", 1),
    new TableHeader("Column6", 6, Alignment.Right),
    new TableHeader("Column7", 2, Alignment.Right),
};
```

Where the second parameter in TableHeader constructor is Width.

I'd like to split the above list into N separate lists each of which containing the total maximum number of W width. For example, if W equals to 7, then I need to get 3 lists containing the TableHeader objects, as follows:

1. Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4 (since 3+2+1+1 <= 7).
2. Column5, Column6
3. Column7

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've already implemented. Any better idea?

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, double maxWidth) where T : TableHeader
{
    while (source.Any())
    {
        int skip = 0;

        double totalWidth = 0;
        yield return source.TakeWhile(h =>
        {
            totalWidth += h.Width;
            if (totalWidth <= maxWidth)
                skip++;

            return totalWidth <= maxWidth;
        });

        source = source.Skip(skip);
    }
}
```